# db.cursor - result of query only returns first record

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a situation where ss can be a list like `[30, 31,32]`. The result of this query only returns the first record not the rest of them. I am not sure what is wrong. I changed the code and just gave the ss as a list but produced an error about the arguments conversion.

```
ss=flipped.get(key) 
sss=""
for item in ss: 
      sss=sss+"'"+ str(item)+"',"                                   
      cur4.execute(sqlQ ,str(sss))
```

Comment: You should think about using different names for your variables `ss` and `sss` could get very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Printf-debugging is a good start for you:

```
ss=flipped.get(key)
sss=""
for item in ss:
      sss=sss+"'"+ str(item)+"',"
      print("[{!r}][{!r}]".format(sqlQ, sss))  ### insert this line
      cur4.execute(sqlQ ,str(sss))
```

Then please check if the outputs agree with your expectation.

`"{!r}".format(x)` is equivalent to `"{}".format(repr(x))` (try out on the interactive console)

Comment: I already know the query is not write as put all the values in quotation together like that'' but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: If you can show me what query string you get now and what you want, I might be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks. I used the following code and it is solved now.       sqlQ="Update Table1 set Field1=1 where Field2 in (%s) ;"  % (','.join(['%s'] * len(ss)),)